# #DATASYNC not disappearing after fixing merge

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a report with 4 queries.
I used two of them in my report.
I merged two of them in a report and the report runs fine.
However, if I change anything in the merge (eg. add another dimension to the merge or unmerge) the report only shows #Datasync.

If I repair the merge **as it was**, the report **still** shows #Datasync. How is that possible?

So to clarify:

1. Report works.
2. Change made in the merge: report fails with #DATASYNC
3. Merge restored as it was: report **still** fails with #DATASYNC. Report needs to be completely rebuilt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects on different levels were combined
(user tried to show email of `companyemployee` next to `companyname`).
Logic dictates that this does not work.